# ClassCastException while deploying SAP ME Service Extension in NWDS

Tags: deployment, service, netweaver

I got this error when trying to deploy a MES service extension using NWDS 7.5:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class java.lang.reflect.WeakCache to interface java.util.Map
>
> SourceName: com.sap.me.trace
>
> Location: com.sap.me.trace

Did anyone face this issue before?

Could it be an IDAT problem or some incorrect configurations?

Some guidance or a HelloWorld tutorial for service extension would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Give your service WSDL

Comment: which version of java is NW running?